# Microphone not working with Nikon D7200

Tags: movie, external

I have a Nikon D7200. I have a microphone that works with my Samsung Galaxy S10+ phone. I tried to use this microphone with the camera, but all I am getting is a buzzing sound. No voice.

I know that the inbuilt microphone works, because I can hear my voice after I record a movie.
[image: Microphone Jack Inserted]

This are the settings no the microphone. I have tried to play with these settings going from Auto to Manual and even keeping the microphone off.

[image: Settings on Movie Mode]

I am at a loss to understand this. Does the Nikon not recognize this microphone for some reason? The microphone I am using is

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B074KJ1N3D/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074KJ1N3D)

Comment: I don't know the pinout of the Nikon socket, but the reason is going to be plug/socket incompatibility. See https://superuser.com/a/1568512/347380 for a quick pinout lesson.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as it's not related to photography bit to video. A [recent superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1568512/141595) explains the differences in audio connectors, perhaps that helps?

Comment: Yup - this ad for a D7200 mic shows it wants a TRS not a TRRS. [I hadn't spotted it was a video question, my bad] - https://www.photo24.co.uk/rode-videomic-go-microphone-for-nikon-d7200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This microphone is created for mobile phones and computers which have appropriate socket. If you check the cable you will see it have 4 conductors:

[image]

For cameras (and recording devices) is expected to be with 2 conductors like this (second from left) or with 3 (the third from left)

[image]
(images from Wikipedia)

Comment: Thanks. I was reading amazon answers on that product and someone mentioned it doesn't work on DSLR camera. Thank you for the research you provided.

Comment: It could work with a suitable connector adapter...

Comment: @xenoid, correct. And such adapter can be created at home :)